# jinja2 exception: {% include nav.html with active_page="home" %}

Tags: flask, include, jinja2

I am building a simple website using flask, and I got a weird error on the following line:

```
`{% include nav.html with active_page="home" %}`
```

the error is:

```
`File "/Users/*/*/website/templates/home-uitlaatservice.html", line 21, in template {% include nav.html with active_page="home" %} jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'with'`
```

Even ChatGPT couldn't fix it, he suggested things like changing syntax to:

```
`% include nav.html with {active_page="home"} %}`

`{% include nav.html with (active_page="home") %}`

`{% include nav.html with 'active_page'="home" %}`

`{% include nav.html active_page="home" %}`
```

w3schools uses this as example, and that is exactly what is did:

```
`{% include mymenu.html with me="ALEXANDER" sponsor="W3SCHOOLS" %}`
```

so if you know the answer that means you are smarter then the all-knowing ChatGPT (-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those are correct Jinja syntax. See https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#include

"The included template has access to context of the current template by default"

so, these will work:

```
{% set active_page = "home" %}
{% include "nav.html" %}  {# active_page is available in nav.html #}
```

or in a Flask route:

```
@app.get("/foo")
def foo():
  return render_template("home-uitlaatservice.html", active_page="home")
```

then in `home-uitlaatservice.html`:

```
{% include "nav.html" %} {# active_page is available in nav.html #}
```

Make sure you put quotes around "nav.html" in the `include`

Comment: that fixed it!!! thanks for your help! I didn't think it would be so easy... well you are officially smarter than ChatGPT! (-;